# Android: No Launcher activity found, no problems in Manifest

Tags: android

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fionaheiss.shovelshovel"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:label="DisplayMap" 
              android:name="com.seanheiss.shovelshovel.DisplayMap"  
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I've tried the "name" field as above and just as ".DisplayMap". It is definitely spelled correctly. Could it be because I'm using Slick2D? The file DisplayMap.java extends BasicGame from the Slick2D engine, and has a main method. Maybe it's not an actual activity or something, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: You should post your logcat

Comment: I don't have one, since the app never launches.

Comment: I doubt that you may using wrong activity name in manifest which is not present actually or may be spell mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the Activity tag:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:label="DisplayMap" 
                  android:name="com.seanheiss.shovelshovel.DisplayMap"  
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" > // Also fix this here
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
      </activity> // <-- here
</application>
```

Comment: Aha! You are correct. But, for some reason when I add, that, and do nothing else, it says `The element type "application" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</application>".`

Comment: You also have to add a end tag to application. See my edited answer

Comment: But if you check my manifest in the question, it's already there.

Comment: Yeah, I just forgot to put that in my answer. Are you still getting that error, although you added it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm still getting that error even though </application> is there.

Comment: You did not replace the "/>" with ">" in your starting activity tag- also save and clean the project.

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem to my Java class. It has nothing to do with the AndroidManifest. I'll create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning,

You have to close the `<activity>` tag after the `<intent-filter>`

```
 <activity >  
        <intent-filter>

       -------------------
       ------------------

        </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```